# C programming: Read (double) numbers from text file, line by line to a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a text file created with excel that contains a table of dimensions 36x35. The values are double numbers (e.g. 2.58) and the text file looks like this:

```
1.25  2.31 ...
4.28  2.56 ...
3.27  ...
...   ...
```

I know the dimensions of the table (arr_row, arr_column) so declare a dynamic 2D array:

```
double **MUDG_table;

//dynamic allocate array of MUDG_table (1st Dimension)
MUDG_table = calloc(arr_row,sizeof(int *));

//check if the memory has been allocated correctly
if (MUDG_table==NULL) 
{
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
    return 1; //return with failure
}

for (cv02=0;cv02<arr_row;cv02++)
{
    //dynamic allocate array of MUDG_table (2nd Dimension)
    MUDG_table[cv02] = calloc(arr_column, sizeof(int));

    //check if the memory has been allocated correctly
    if (MUDG_table[cv02]==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return 1; //return with failure
    }
}
```

So far so good. Then I try to read the values from the text file and store them to the array for further processing:

```
//************************************************************************************************************//
//read the text file with the values of the gain and save it to the MUDG_table
//************************************************************************************************************//

gain_ptr = fopen("MUDG_text.txt", "r");

if (gain_ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    return 1; //return with failure
}

for (row=0;row<arr_row;row++)
{
    for (column=0;column<arr_column;column++)
    {
        fscanf(gain_ptr, " %1f", &MUDG_table[row][column]);
    }
}

fclose(gain_ptr);
```

and the problem is that the values I get are something like 5.26346e-315#DEN 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong. Is it because I do not use the EOF?

Comment: `MUDG_table = calloc(arr_row,sizeof(int *));` This is wrong. You should **always** write `x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * ...);`. In this case it's `MUDG_table = calloc(arr_row,sizeof(*MUDG_table));`

Comment: Maybe this is the reason: `sizeof(int)` is wrong when you want to store `float` or `double` values.

Comment: `double` and `int` have not the same size. Especially here `calloc(arr_column, sizeof(int));`

Comment: @Eregrith Does this has something to do with the passing of the values from the text file? because up to this point all the arrays I use in my code are like this and I never have had a problem.

Comment: So it should be `size of calloc(arr_column, sizeof(double)`?

Comment: @kat no, it should be `MUDG_table[cv02] = calloc(arr_column, sizeof(*MUDG_table[cv02]));`. This way, if ever you change MUDG_table definition, you won't need to go through all your code to change all of that

Comment: @Eregrith I did it, but still it is not working properly... I still get those strange values

Comment: @kat Try adding `printf("Got this: [%1f]\n", MUDG_table[row][column]);` after `fscanf(gain_ptr, " %1f", &MUDG_table[row][column]);`

Comment: @Eregrith All the results are zero (0.0000). I just read in a previous post that: _FYI, the correct way to read floating-point numbers in C is to use fgets and strtod. DO NOT use either atof or scanf for this; atof doesn't tell you about syntax errors, and scanf triggers undefined behavior on overflow._ Is there any chance that this is the problem?

Comment: @kat, yes `strtod` would be a much better way to go.

Comment: @CarlNorum I am trying but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after going through several posts and thanks to the responses I got here, I changed the code and it seams to work properly.

First of all the array should be declared as double:

```
//dynamic allocate array of MUDG_table (1st Dimension)
MUDG_table = calloc(arr_row,sizeof(double *));

//check if the memory has been allocated correctly
if (MUDG_table==NULL) 
{
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
    return 1; //return with failure
}

for (cv02=0;cv02<arr_row;cv02++)
{
    MUDG_table[cv02] = calloc(arr_column, sizeof(double));

    //check if the memory has been allocated correctly
    if (MUDG_table[cv02]==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return 1; //return with failure
    }
}
```

The main problem was the fscanf which I have no idea why it is not working. So I replaced it with the fgets. I found this code in another post and I modified it to work in this case.

```
gain_ptr = fopen("MUDG_text.txt", "r");

if (gain_ptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    return 1; //return with failure
}

for (row=0;row<arr_row;row++)
{
    fgets(buffer, 1024, gain_ptr); //buffer is declared as char buffer[1024];

    tok = strtok(buffer, "\t");    // NULL means 'continue from last token'  
    //tok is declared as char *tok;
    //the numbers in my text file are seperated by tabs
    //so the tokens should be separated by \t

    column = 0;  //since fgets gets a whole line I had to separate the columns
    while (tok != NULL) 
    {
        test_var = atof(tok);  //test variable is declared as double
        //and it is used to hold temporarily the value of tok in double
        tok = strtok(NULL, "\t");    // NULL means 'continue from last token'

        MUDG_table[row][column] = test_var;
        column++;
    }
}   
fclose(gain_ptr);
```

Maybe it is not the best solution, but at least it works.